# The movement of a bowling ball while throwing it

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-velocity

When a bowler pushes a bowling ball into the lane he rotate his wrist so he apply a force to rotate the ball if I only Know the angle of rotation and the value of the force how can I find the angular velocity and the angular acceleration if it has an acceleration... I started like this...

$$\vec a = \frac{\vec F}{m} $$

this acceleration can be divided into two acceleration, the tangential and centripetal.

$a_t=\frac{dv}{dt}$

$a_c=\frac{v^2}{r}$

I am not sure if that is right and I don't know what to do next to get the angular velocity and the angular acceleration?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you might need the angular equations of motion

https://isaacphysics.org/concepts/cp_ang_eq_of_motion

You might also need $T=I \alpha$, where $T$ is torque, $I$ is moment of inertia and $\alpha$ is angular acceleration.